# file index is not found in a code for uploading files

Tags: php, html

I have copied this code from w3school website in my edditor (link: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp) and  this error is echoed:

Undefined index: fileToUpload

I can't find any syntax or semantic problem in it and in php.ini  file file_uploads directive is set to on.

```
<?php
echo <<<htmlcode
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to upload:
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
htmlcode;
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file ". basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

When you run the page this block will run too. And when you didn't click submit button  page read `fileToUpload` and see there is nothing named `fileToUpload` so you get the error.

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
   if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
      echo "The file ". basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been 
uploaded.";
   } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
   }
 }
```

Add this lines in to if condition

```
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
```

like

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) 
 {
    echo "The file ". basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been 
 uploaded.";
  } else {
    echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your variables and other code inside the if statement brackets the code is trying to run before you have even uploaded your image so the isset will make sure you uploaded the image first before running any php code.

Also in you html the action="yourfilename.php`" make sure its the name of your file so if its`upload.php`make sure the action is`upload.php`

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
      $target_dir = "Uploads/";
      $target_file = $target_dir . basename ($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file ". basename ($_FILE["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }
    ?>
```